# Why does my modal page have a back button?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

**Project and problem explanation**

In my case I have a page which instructs the user how to move a certain machine. This page is supposed to be a modal page since the page should not be navigated away from without performing or completely canceling the action.

[image]
I have a mainpage with a listview which opens the details page of any of the items contained in the listview on click through the onSelect method:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new FooPage(string Name)); /* gets called in the 
onSelect method if selection is not null*/
```

The model is retrieved within the details page's viewmodel after passing the name to it and then using a model manager injected into the viewmodel with Unity to retrieve it.

-- we now both have a mainpage and detailspage on the stack which of only the detailspage has a backbutton --

On the detailspage we have a button called "Teach" with a x,y,z field next to it after clicking it this method gets called:

```
private async Task Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ManualTeachPage());
        }
```

which then, as it should, creates the page but then for some reason decides to add a back button to it:
[image: Uwp backbutton is visible]

**Debugging and Research**

This behavior is not visible on Android which does not have a visible back button or navigation bar on this page but does have a backbutton on the *Details*-page as well.

I have used modal pages before but I have never seen this kind of behavior, I have tried using the Navigation property of the Application.Mainpage itself which resulted in the exact same result except for one case.

I thought it might have something to do with me switching out the Application.Mainpage at one point(there is a stack of tutorial pages the user has to go through), seems like calling the pushModalAsync one line AFTER setting the new mainpage then it DOES push the page as a modal page and performs like one (without a back button) but does not do so after this point.

No bug reports on Bugzilla about this either as far as I have seen, neither have I found anything on the internet about this particular problem.

Note that when clicking the back button on the teachPage it returns to the detailspage. When the teachPage gets pushed it does actually get pushed onto the ModalStack.

*update 1*

Checked again if the modal page which I was talking about was the only modal page on the modal Stack, it was. NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); does not seem to work either as suggested by Diego Rafael Souza.

*update 2*

I thought I would temporarily disable the backbutton by using the onBackButtonPressed within the teachpage until I had found a solution. Turns out this doesn't work for UWP anymore, this method does not get called anymore on this page or any page for that matter. It does work for the Android Hardware button though.

*update 3*

I tried using:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = 
AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
```

This does hide the backbutton on UWP but for some reason #if WINDOWS_UWP doesn't work at all. If I do this without the #if the program won't build for Android. No solution yet, not only this but when using this fix the other pages still had the onBackButtonPressed method disabled.

*update 4*

after updating to the newest version of xamarin forms the OnBackButtonPressed started working again. The backbutton still appears on the page but I now have disabled it.

**Recreating the problem**

I recreated the problem in this small test project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6btsud3uvw503ee/AAAiaGb3TwhMrZMJb2j-rd36a?dl=0

Comment: I know the navigation has two stacks of pages, the page in question is the only modal page on the modal stack. the detailspage is pushed on the normal navigation stack which is the page before that.

I might be misunderstanding you here, but do you mean trying to use  NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); in the TeachPage constructor? Because that didn't work for me.

Comment: I have your Test Project, but I'm not sure which "page" is the modal in question. Could you advise so I can attempt to help?

Comment: It is the teachPage, the last page you'll go to when navigating through all the pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your function `Button_Clicked()` in your example, in page `DetailPage`, where you call your Modal, right after calling `PushModalAsync(new TeachPage());`, use:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

My guess is when you tried using the above `SetHasBackButton`, you were doing it on the Modal itself, but the back button you were actually seeing came from your DetailPage.

Once you add this, the modal pops up, and the back button disappears. If you  set a "Back" button on your modal in order to close it, you can easily get your NavBar and BackButton back in your DetailPage by adding in an `OnAppearing()` Function in your DetailPage code-behind like so:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing(); // do the usual stuff OnAppearing does
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true); //get your navbar back
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true); //get your back button back
}
```

Comment: I actually thought it came from the DetailsPage at first but because it went back to the detailsPage and not the mainPage when clicking the back button, I discarded the idea. 

This is definitely a workaround, but acceptable enough to use. Would have loved some kind of clue of what actually happened though, I will hold off on giving you the bounty but will mark it as the answer.

If there's no better answer I'll reward it

Comment: @Lloyd no problem - not too worried about it. Glad this will work for you for now.